# How Spring Sidecar Works with Docker

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

We have a sidecar application that to enable us to register our node.js application with Eureka to enable service discovery.

Our sidecar application configuration looks like:

```
server:
  port: 9000

spring:
  application:
    name: session-service

sidecar:
  port: 3000
  health-url: http://sessionServiceNode:${sidecar.port}/health.json

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://discoveryService:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 5
    prefer-ip-address: true
```

As per the config, our node application is running on port `3000` defined by the `sidecar.port` property, and our sidecar application should run on port `9000` as per `server.port`.

We have added a endpoint to our node application to allow the sidecar to check the health of the application (`sidecar.health-url`). The hostname `sessionServiceNode` is the name of the alias we've given to the container running our node application.

Our Eureka service is running in a separate container also linked to the sidecar application container via the alias discoveryService.

We have a separate test spring boot application which runs in a seperate container which is a consumer of the session service. This container is solely linked to the discovery service container.

The sidecar application registers itself with Eureka as expected

[image]

The test service uses two forms of lookup for the session service. One uses a feign client:

```
@FeignClient(value = "session-service") // name of our registered service in eureka
interface SessionServiceClient {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/document/get/24324", method = GET)
    String documentGetTest();

}
```

And the other method uses a more programmatic lookup:

```
@Autowired
private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

...
discoveryClient.getInstances("session-service");
```

When we make a request to the test service, the test service does a lookup for the session service, however the instance info the eureka gives us back has the URI of: `http://172.17.0.5:3000` which is incorrect. `172.17.0.5` is the IP address of the sidecar application container, but the port `3000` is what the node application is running on?

Should be expect to see eureka return us the location of the session service container with the session service port (`http://172.17.0.5:9000`), and then sidecar does the 'forwarding' to the node application for us (`http://172.17.0.6:3000`) via a zuul proxy? Or should Eureka give us the location of the node application directly?

I have included the session-service instance information from Eureka below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application>
   <name>SESSION-SERVICE</name>
   <instance>
      <hostName>172.17.0.5</hostName>
      <app>SESSION-SERVICE</app>
      <ipAddr>172.17.0.5</ipAddr>
      <status>UP</status>
      <overriddenstatus>UNKNOWN</overriddenstatus>
      <port enabled="true">3000</port>
      <securePort enabled="false">443</securePort>
      <countryId>1</countryId>
      <dataCenterInfo class="com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo">
         <name>MyOwn</name>
      </dataCenterInfo>
      <leaseInfo>
         <renewalIntervalInSecs>5</renewalIntervalInSecs>
         <durationInSecs>90</durationInSecs>
         <registrationTimestamp>1461223810081</registrationTimestamp>
         <lastRenewalTimestamp>1461224812429</lastRenewalTimestamp>
         <evictionTimestamp>0</evictionTimestamp>
         <serviceUpTimestamp>1461223810081</serviceUpTimestamp>
      </leaseInfo>
      <metadata class="java.util.Collections$EmptyMap" />
      <homePageUrl>http://c892e0c03cf4:3000/</homePageUrl>
      <statusPageUrl>http://c892e0c03cf4:9000/info</statusPageUrl>
      <healthCheckUrl>http://c892e0c03cf4:9000/health</healthCheckUrl>
      <vipAddress>session-service</vipAddress>
      <isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>false</isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>
      <lastUpdatedTimestamp>1461223810081</lastUpdatedTimestamp>
      <lastDirtyTimestamp>1461223033045</lastDirtyTimestamp>
      <actionType>ADDED</actionType>
   </instance>
</application>
```

**EDIT:**

After looking at the code, Eureka uses the host information returned from `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()` and `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()` respectively to determine the address of the instance. This is why we're getting the IP address of the sidecar container. Is there any way we can override this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So by the looks of it Sidecar makes the assumption that the spring boot sidecar application and the non-jvm application are running on the same host. In our scenario we run everything in separate containers. One container for our sidecar jvm application, and one container for our node.js application. We could in theory have both applications running in the same container, but this violates Docker's best practices of having one unix process per container.

To get this to work, we have overridden the `EurekaInstanceConfigBean`, which allows us to control what hostname and IP address that get's chosen for the instance. In this case, we delegate to the `inetUtils` class and lookup the IP address from a hostname (which is the alias of the non jvm application linked via docker). We have made use of spring `@ConfigurationProperties` to control the hostname/port from the `application.yml` configuration file.

*SessionServiceSidecar.java*

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
public class SessionServiceSidecarProperties {

    @Value("${sidecar.hostname}")
    private String hostname;

    @Value("${sidecar.port}")
    private Integer port;

    public String getHostname() {
        return hostname;
    }

    public Integer getPort() {
        return port;
    }

}
```

*SessionServiceApp.java*

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSidecar
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class SessionServiceApp {

    private @Autowired SessionServiceSidecarProperties properties;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SessionServiceApp.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public EurekaInstanceConfigBean eurekaInstanceConfigBean(InetUtils inetUtils) {

        final String sidecarHostname = properties.getHostname();
        final Integer sidecarPort = properties.getPort();

        try {

            final EurekaInstanceConfigBean instance = new EurekaInstanceConfigBean(inetUtils);
            instance.setHostname(sidecarHostname);
            instance.setIpAddress(inetUtils.convertAddress(InetAddress.getByName(sidecarHostname)).getIpAddress());
            instance.setNonSecurePort(sidecarPort);
            return instance;

        } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not resolve IP address of sidecar application using hostname: " + sidecarHostname);
        }

    }

}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: session-service

server:
  port: 9000

sidecar:
  hostname: sessionServiceNode
  port: 3000
  health-url: http://sessionServiceNode:${sidecar.port}/health.json

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://discoveryService:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 5
    prefer-ip-address: true
```

Hopefully the Spring guys will allow us to control the hostname of the sidecar application aswell as the port via a `sidecar.hostname` property in the future.

Hope this helps!

Comment: submit an issue and or PR.

Comment: Issue already raised https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/981, PR incoming

Answer (score 0):

Spring Cloud is picking the first non-loopback ip address. You can do one of a couple of things.

One: Ignore the network interfaces you don't want to choose from. Docs [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-commons.adoc#ignore-network-interfaces).

```
spring:
  cloud:
    inetutils:
      ignoredInterfaces:
        - docker0
        - veth.*
```

Or two: explicitly set the ipaddress or hostname that eureka registers (if you use the same docker alias everywhere. For hostname set `eureka.instance.hostname=sessionServiceNode` and remove the `prefer-ip-address=true` option. For ip addr, `eureka.instance.ipAddress=<ipaddr>`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. We have made the change to the sidecar configuration to ignore the docker interfaces, however Eureka still returns the IP address of the sidecar container, not the IP address of the node application container. Option #2 isn't really viable for us at this stage, as we would have to link every consuming service to the node container for the hostname to resolve properly, which defeats the purpose!